# What should be done about questions where the answer is directly found in the API?

Tags: discussion

For example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23592668/what-is-null-for-in-a-call-of-joptionpane-showmessagedialog) is one such question. It is clear that the publicly available and easily googleable API has the direct answer to the question.

Quite a few of the low quality questions could be solved with a quick look to the API, and the faster this is learned the better.

Furthermore, the only real answers would be to copy & paste the API there, or otherwise just say the same information with your own words. **Or just give simple link to the documentation, which is what usually happens, a link only answer.**

The obvious way forwards would be to down vote the question for the lack of research effort.

Should these questions be flagged as very low quality as well? Should I just refrain from flagging them altogether? Would a more specific close reason be useful?

Comment: I would just downvote it. Just because it shows no effort doesn't mean it isn't on-topic.

Comment: Just an observation: When googling for something I've learned that if get hits both to API docs and SO I often check the SO Q&A instead because the examples and explanations are often clearer and to the point. Sometimes I do that after taking a look at the docs, observing that they are somehow complex or unclear, I check if there'd happen to be a SO Q&A about instead. I don't mean to say that this would be good use of SO but is anyhow how the site has served me well recently. I wouldn't ask just questions but am happy to see the answers..

Comment: @antont I agree, sometimes the API is just unclear/wrong/nonexistant.

Comment: @anont duplication is still an issue, though.

Comment: Just because you could find it doesn't mean they could, sometimes people are so new to something they don't even know how to ask the question, or the docs are written in a way that is over their head.  In the question you reference, he's obviously a noob and is wondering why do I have to pass null as the first parameter, what else could I pass instead of it.  And as to that being good docs...  well lets just say they leave a lot to be desired.  The actual information he needed was WAAAAAY past the fold and 6 matches down the page.  I could see how a noob would be numb by then.

Comment: Also remember that google customizes your results based on your site history.  So, it's possible that your top link isn't their top link.